# Kotlin/Native how to create Array of CPointers?

Tags: kotlin, pointers, generics, kotlin-native

I'm new to Kotlin/Native! I'd like to create an array of CPointers to pass it around, but having hard time creating one.

In C/C++ `void* a[] = {test}` is enough. But I'm not able to do the same in K/N.

I've tried `val a: CValuesRef<out COpaquePointerVar> = cValuesOf(test)`

But it results in the following error:

[image]

Tried looking at docs and find it on the web, but none of them answered correctly.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I basically did what I wanted using a [`StableRef`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlinx.cinterop/-stable-ref/)

```kotlin
on_exit(staticCFunction { _, argsPtr ->
    val argsStableRef = argsPtr!!.asStableRef<List<COpaquePointer>>()
    val args = argsStableRef.get()

    // Cleanup code

    argsStableRef.dispose()
}, StableRef.create(listOf(/* All the pointers */)).asCPointer())
```

Basically transforming the `List<COpaquePointer>` to a StableRef and extracting pointer out of it, then when required deref it via the [`asStableRef`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlinx.cinterop/as-stable-ref.html) and after that dispose it to ensure memory have been freed.